# How come it is possible to put a pointer twice in a vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr

Shouldn't `std::unique_ptr` prevent the possibility of such an error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct B {
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> v;  // unique_ptr can be stored in a container
    B* p = new B;
    v.emplace_back(p);
    std::cout << "p:" <<p <<"\n";
    std::cout << "v[0]:"<<v[0].get() << "\n";
    v.emplace_back(p);
    std::cout << "p:" <<p <<"\n";
    std::cout << "v[1]:"<<v[1].get() << "\n";

}
```

Error message when double free is detected:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001094c20 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f3da200b7e5]
...
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3228321                            /tmp/1617748074.6996937/a.out
...
```

Output when double free is ignored:

```
p:0x1094c20
v[0]:0x1094c20
p:0x1094c20
v[1]:0x1094c20
```

Comment: You're only supposed to put a specific single pointer into a unique_ptr _once_.  When you do it thinks it owns it, and will free it.  It doesn't know you've already put it into some _other_ unique_ptr.  You've got to not do that. (Think about how it could possibly prevent the situation you're describing: Each unique_ptr has to know about _all other_ unique_ptrs you've got to make sure its the only one holding what it's holding?  No.  It's on you to use it correctly.)

Comment: It should work like this. You construct two unique pointer from the same raw pointer, so both tries to deallocate it at the end

Comment: Remember that a pointer is one-way only. There is no mechanism for a pointer to know who else is pointing at an object  `shared_ptr` doesn't even know who else is pointing. It only knows the count.

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid this possibility by religiously using [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: @davidbak not just all other `unique_ptr<B>`s, all `B`s (that might have automatic or static storage duration)

Comment: C++ does not stop you from doing incorrect things

Comment: By what algorithm should the `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` prevent this error?

Comment: Howard Hinnant, lately I have been studying unique_ptr a lot. I would never use it this way. But somehow I would have expected it to only allow constructing from rvalue. That is clearly not the case.

Comment: `unique_ptr` doesn't construct from an lvalue or an rvalue, it constructs from a pointer.

Comment: @MarshallClow,  hm, I think you know this matter better than me, but between `B* p = new B; std::unique_ptr<B> x(p);` and `std::unique_ptr<B> x(new B);`, the first one is constructing from lvalue and the second one from rvalue, right?

Comment: `p` is an lvalue, but as you've seen `unique_ptr` doesn't care. All it wants is the object that `p` points at and takes a pointer by value (remember that a pointer is just another variable and can be passed by value or reference depending on the needs of the function). For details see constructor overloads 3 and 4 [at this documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr). Most of the really gory details have to do with how the optional deleter is passed.

Comment: Side note: In case you haven't been exposed to how much fun rvalues can get, give [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) a read.

Comment: Supposing that `std::unique_ptr` (could and) did “prevent the possibility of such an error”—what would that look like?  Would the program not compile, and if so based on what static(!) rule?  Would it raise an exception, and if so at what runtime cost?

Answer (score 6):

`std::unique_ptr` can prevent double free bugs if used properly:

- Never create an owning raw pointer; use `std::make_unique`.
- If you must absolutely create an owning raw pointer using `new` (*i.e.* in order
  to call a private constructor from a factory function), then do so
  within a statement that immediately wraps the raw pointer in a
  `std::unique_ptr` and does nothing else, *e.g.* `return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived(...));`
- Do not use the `std::unique_ptr` constructor that takes a raw pointer in any other context.

If these guidelines are followed, each `unique_ptr` will manage an object that is not managed by anyone else. If they are not followed, there is a possibility of bugs like the one you observed, where multiple `unique_ptr` instances can be created from the same raw pointer. Neither instance is "aware" that the raw pointer you pass to it is already owned by another instance. If the `unique_ptr` constructor had to check whether anyone else owns the pointer, it would introduce performance overhead for every single user. We use C++ to avoid such unnecessary overhead. It is unnecessary as long as you follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Minimal example (no need for `vector`):

```
struct B {
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    B* p = new B;
    std::unique_ptr<B> x(p);
    std::unique_ptr<B> y(p);
}
```

You have two `unique_ptr`s who believe that they own the same raw pointer. They're both going to call `delete` on that pointer, and you get a double free.  Putting the `unique_ptr`s in a container doesn't change that.

Comment: Nice simplification. I have submitted a change from `x(b)` to `x(p)`. In the original wrong version you have `std::unique_ptr<B> x(b);` what is wrong. However, it must be approved first.